# How to output a temporary file in API service in Java, and delete it in the end?

Tags: java, file, swagger, openapi

I am writing an API service that fetches data from a stream, and outputs it in a file. I can't output it as a stream because I use Swagger (now OpenAPI) 2.0, which doesn't support output streams (Swagger 3.0 does, but i can't use it).

What would be the cleanest way to make a file, output it via the service, and then make sure it gets deleted?

I initially thought I might use a temp file and delete in `finally` clause. However, there is no guarantee that the file finished downloading on the client side before that clause is reached and file is deleted.

Am I right? Wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `File.createTempFile()` and `file.deleteOnExit()`

Comment: This will not help me as I am running a long-lived API service so never exiting (unless I release new version).

Comment: Then using a `finally` to delete the file should work. Unless you ended up deleting it too early.

Comment: Exactly. Was wondering if there was a safer way though.

Comment: Why not bypass the file entirely and save it in memory using a `ByteArrayInput/OutputStream`

Comment: Because I can only return a file. No way around it.

Comment: using `finally` seems fine then. Might even be able to make a closeable File proxy which deletes the file when you're done with it

Answer (score 0):

I was talking about using a closeable in the comments. This is it.

Usage:

```
try (TempFile file = new TempFile("tempfile", ".txt")) {
    // do stuff with file
} catch (IOException e) {
    // error handling.
    // file should be automatically deleted.
}
```

TempFile:

```
public class TempFile implements AutoCloseable {

    private final File file;

    public TempFile(String prefix, String suffix) {
        this.file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.file.delete();
    }
}
```